# Displaying the user selection

Tags: php, javascript, prototype

I have a price range slider added to a php search form, and its using Prototype.
Here is the *form* code:

```
<input type="text" name="pmin" id="pmin" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
/>
<input type="text" name="pmax" id="pmax" value="500" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
/>
<div id="price-range" class="filter-track"> <span id="pminx" class="filter-handle" title="Scroll to set minimum value"></span>

    <span
    id="pmaxx" class="filter-handle" title="Scroll to set maximum value"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the *javascript* code that handles the slider:

```
<script>
    var loadPriceSlider = function () {
        var handles = [$('pminx'), $('pmaxx')];
        // horizontal slider control with preset values
        priceRange = new Control.Slider(handles, 'price-range', {
            range: $R(0, 500, false),
            sliderValue: [0, 500],
            values: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500],
            restricted: true,
            onSlide: function (v) {
                $('pmin').value = ((v[0] != null) ? v[0] : 0);
                $('pmax').value = ((v[1] != null) ? v[1] : 0);
            },
            onChange: function (v) {
                if (v.length > 0) {
                    $('pmin').value = ((v[0] != null) ? v[0] : 0);
                    $('pmax').value = ((v[1] != null) ? v[1] : 0);
                }
            }
        });
    };
    loadPriceSlider();
</script>
```

I need to have the selections made by user displayed in the search result page. Currently the form works, if the user makes some selections on this price slider, the right results are displayed but the input displays the min and max values as 0 and 500, the default ones.

Answer (score 0):

To assign value in jquery you should use like

```
$('#pmin').val((v[0] != null) ? v[0] : 0));
$('#pmax').val((v[1] != null) ? v[1] : 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what plugin you are using. but if it has a `default`option, or an `initial value` option, you could pass the default values from php... something like

```
priceRange = new Control.Slider(handles, 'price-range', {
        range: $R(0, 500, false),
   ---> default: [<?php echo $min; ?>, <?php echo $max; ?>], // or initial or something
        sliderValue: [0, 500],
```

and control the $min and $max from php. So after the search is submited, you will pass the previous values to the JS plugin.

Hope this helps

Comment: The search results are displayed in same page as the form.

Comment: that doesn't change anything.. :)